# Aws-Lambda export default function does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am practicing aws lambda function and serverless yml. I am using typescript and javascript es6. I testing my serverless yml file by offline plugins. When I export the lambda function and call it in serverless yml file like this: `handler: src/handlers/hello.hello`, my lambda trigger the function and It works as expected. I am trying to my lambda function as export default function and call it like this `handler: src/handlers/hello.default`. I am getting error: `hello is not a function`. I don't know what I am doing wrong in my export default.

**This logic works**

```
import { APIGatewayEvent } from "aws-lambda";

export async function hello(event: APIGatewayEvent) {

  console.log(event);

  try {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify("hello emmy"),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    };
  }

}
```

**This export default does not work**

```
import { APIGatewayEvent } from "aws-lambda";

export default async function hello(event: APIGatewayEvent) {
  try {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify("hello world"),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a lot of it likely comes down to your serverless config. I am using `serverless-bundle` as a plugin via:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-bundle
```

in order to be able to leverage ES6 and other modern javascript goodies in my Lambda that has been created with the Serverless framework.

I create and export my function like this:

```
export default async function (event)
```

and then in my serverless.yml set handler like this:

```
handler: handler.default
```

This has got all things running properly on my end.

Comment: Excellent. This works. Thanks.

Comment: This works, but creates raises linting errors from the unnamed function.